# Are there any software tools which can deeply analyse pronunciation errors?

Tags: pronunciation

I have only ever seen pronunciation taught in terms of body mechanics, that is, "In language X, the "I" sound is produced with the lips more rounded than the English "I"", for example. There are apps like Babbel which approve or reject a given pronunciation, but do not analyse it deeply, so far as I have seen.

Therefore: is it possible to go through the phonemes of a language, repeating them into your iPhone, seeing the spectrogram of the sound, having the computer analyse in what way the sound is wrong (these frequencies are wrong, it needs to have more of this contour, etc.), and even respond with the changes in body mechanics necessary to correct this?

Or, anything roughly similar to this, in any language?

Comment: There are roughly 7000 languages in the world. Which one are you particularly interested in?

Comment: You can do quite a lot of that in Praat, which is a free download for Windows / Mac / Linux(?). There's a bit of a learning curve but it's worthwhile if you are interested in the technicalities.